# How to add unclosed JSX tag?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
{props.href && (
    <Link href={props.href}>
        <button>
            {props.children}
        </button>
    </Link>
)}
{!props.href && (
    <button>
        {props.children}
    </button>
)}
```

How can I simplify it to something like this:

```
{props.href && ( <Link href={props.href}>   )}
    <button>
        {props.children}
    </button>
{props.href && ( </Link>    )}
```

I get syntax errors for this code because I open Link tag without closing it.

Answer (score 0):

You must close an opened tag in JSX! You could simplify the code instead by using a ternary operator like,

```
{props.href ? (
    <Link href={props.href}>
        <button>
            {props.children}
        </button>
    </Link>) : (
    <button>
        {props.children}
    </button>
)}
```